# Empty summary chart in Google App Engine (service is up and running)

Tags: google-app-engine

For some reason summary and traffic (not traffic VM) remain empty for running in Google App Engine (flex environment) service. Anybody have same issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this reported into google support a bug on their side was fixed. Chart works now.